# About Spool Command

Tags: oracle11g

set echo off

spool C:\Drop_Script_Oracle.sql

select 'drop table '|| table_name ||';' from all_tables where Lower(owner)  = 'plat911';

spool off;

Above commands are not outputing the result of sql query to Drop_Script_Oracle.sql file.Can Someone same me where the problem is?

Comment: What is getting output?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?

Comment: to help you debug try a: spool C:\test.sql; select '1' from dual; spool off; type script, does that work?

Comment: Hi justin Cave,
            I am uisng Oracle Sql developer to run those commands.It doesn't give me any error but it is orinting the output of command in output screeb but I want it to return the output to Drop_Script_Oracle.sql file.

Comment: Hi tolanj,
     The script you said is not returning any output to test.sql file